# Change a repeated record inside another repeated record into a flat set of fields

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics

I am working with Google Analytics data and would like to transform the customDimensions and hits.customDimensions fields from having index-value pairs to being a flat set of subfields.  For instance, if I had data like

| hits.hitNumber | hits.customDimension.index | hits.customDimension.value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | a |
|  | 1 | b |
| 2 | 0 | a |
|  | 2 | c |
|  | 1 | d |

to be replaced by

| hits.hitNumber | hits.cd_0 | hits.cd_1 | hits.cd_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b |  |
| 2 | a | d | c |

while keeping all other data the same. I am running into issues with the use of UNNEST currently where I am getting duplicate records.

I am currently stuck at

```
(
   SELECT CASE
   WHEN hcd.index = 0 then hcd.value
   WHEN cd.index = 0 then cd.value
   ELSE NULL
   END AS temp
   FROM UNNEST(hits) h, UNNEST(h.customDimensions) AS hcd, 
   UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS cd
   WHERE hcd.index=0 or cd.index=0
   LIMIT 1
) as cd_0
```

and the query seems to only be getting the values from the first hit. I think somehow I have to add this cd_0 field as a subfield for each entry in an array of hits records. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the best solution is a combination of SELECT * REPLACE function and nested subqueries:

```
SELECT *
    REPLACE((
        SELECT AS STRUCT * 
        REPLACE((
            SELECT AS STRUCT
                (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) x WHERE x.index=0) cd_0,
                (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) x WHERE x.index=1) cd_1,
                (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) x WHERE x.index=2) cd_2
            ) AS customDimensions
        )
    FROM UNNEST(hits) h
    ) AS hits
)
FROM t
```

You can also toggle the field hits.customDimensions to be REPEATED by using ARRAY( in place of the second ( after REPLACE.

To give credit, I found the SELECT * REPLACE(( SELECT AS STRUCT <some_struct> )) part in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642230/replace-nested-repeated-fields) and the nested subquery part [here](https://robertsahlin.com/flatten-google-analytics-custom-dimensions-with-a-bigquery-udf/?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=Google%20BigQuery%20-%20flatten%20your%20Google%20Analytics%20custom%20dimensions&utm_content=link#unnest).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a SQL server solution: I think you need to modify according to your database/Datawarehouse.

```
with cte as
    (
        select 
            * ,
            row_number() over(order by (select null)) as seq 
        from customDimension 
    )
    select coalesce(b.[hist.hitNumber], a.maxHitNumber) as [hist.hitNumber] ,
    max(case when b.[hist.customDimensionIndex] = 0 then b.[hist.customDimensionValue] end) as [cd_0] , 
    max(case when b.[hist.customDimensionIndex] = 1 then b.[hist.customDimensionValue] end) as [cd_1] ,
    max(case when b.[hist.customDimensionIndex] = 2 then b.[hist.customDimensionValue] end) as [cd_2]
    from
    (
        select b.seq , max(a.[hist.hitNumber]) as maxHitNumber from
        (select * from cte where [hist.hitNumber] is not null) as a inner join cte as b on a.seq <= b.seq
        group by b.seq
    ) as a inner join cte as b on a.seq = b.seq
    group by coalesce(b.[hist.hitNumber], a.maxHitNumber);
```

Comment: Hmm. I added my own solution that works in BigQuery.  One issue I am seeing in your solution is that it doesn't have UNNEST function to handle REPEATED fields (arrays), so I am thinking it's not quite the answer one is looking for, but maybe its still useful in SQL Server context. Thank you for trying!

Comment: I don't think SQL server doesn't have UNNEST function available. I think the solution might work. I will have to modify the code if I want to do it in a different database. Thank you for letting me know.